# create a deamon process in android

Tags: java, android, android-service, daemon

For the project in android that I am having I need to make a **server as daemon process** to handle request in the background even if the app is closed.

Is there any way to create a daemon process. If so will it killed by app on exit. or How to kill the daemon process/threads in android.

Can i have an example **syntax** regarding the creation of Daemon process.

If A is my app main process and B is my daemon server process. If A is killed and B got a request that invokes some functionality of A, then the A main will start or what will happen

Comment: What you have tried?. Android service is the right option.

Comment: I have tried in the normal way t.setDaemon(true);  If so will it always run in background. and how can i initialte intent in android by the Daemon thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I get it right; you are looking for android services and here is something that can help you with that:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

and yes there are many ways to shutdown a service check out the tutorials for more information.